# Printing image with PrintDocument. how to adjust the image to fit paper size

Tags: c#, printing, printdocument

In C#, I am trying to print an image using PrintDocument class with the below code. The image is of size 1200 px width and 1800 px height. I am trying to print this image in a 4*6 paper using a small zeebra printer. But the program is printing only 4*6 are of the big image. that means it is not adjusting the image to the paper size !

```
     PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
     pd.PrintPage += (sender, args) =>
     {
           Image i = Image.FromFile("C://tesimage.PNG");
           Point p = new Point(100, 100);
           args.Graphics.DrawImage(i, 10, 10, i.Width, i.Height);
     };
     pd.Print();
```

When i print the same image using Window Print (right click and select print, it is scaling automatically to paper size and printing correctly. that means everything came in 4*6 paper.) How do i do the same in my C# program ?

Comment: If you like an answer, accept it. It gives credit to the person that answered you and helps other people who search for an answer to find the proper one faster

Answer (score 39):

The parameters that you are passing into the DrawImage method should be the size you want the image on the paper rather than the size of the image itself, the DrawImage command will then take care of the scaling for you. Probably the easiest way is to use the following override of the DrawImage command.

```
args.Graphics.DrawImage(i, args.MarginBounds);
```

Note: This will skew the image if the proportions of the image are not the same as the rectangle. Some simple math on the size of the image and paper size will allow you to create a new rectangle that fits in the bounds of the paper without skewing the image.

Comment: This should be the answer! Thanks for the solution it works as expected.

Comment: args.Graphics.DrawImage(i, args.PageBounds);

Answer (score 32):

Not to trample on BBoy's already decent answer, but I've done the code that maintains aspect ratio.  I took his suggestion, so he should get partial credit here!

```
PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
pd.DefaultPageSettings.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "Printer Name";
pd.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true; //or false!
pd.PrintPage += (sender, args) =>
{
    Image i = Image.FromFile(@"C:\...\...\image.jpg");
    Rectangle m = args.MarginBounds;

    if ((double)i.Width / (double)i.Height > (double)m.Width / (double)m.Height) // image is wider
    {
        m.Height = (int)((double)i.Height / (double)i.Width * (double)m.Width);
    }
    else
    {
        m.Width = (int)((double)i.Width / (double)i.Height * (double)m.Height);
    }
    args.Graphics.DrawImage(i, m);
};
pd.Print();
```

Comment: Good answer, but I replaced args.MarginBounds with args.PageBounds

Answer (score 10):

The solution provided by BBoy works fine. But in my case I had to use

```
e.Graphics.DrawImage(memoryImage, e.PageBounds);
```

This will print only the form. When I use MarginBounds it prints the entire screen even if the form is smaller than the monitor screen. PageBounds solved that issue. Thanks to BBoy!

Answer (score 4):

**You can use my code here**

```
//Print Button Event Handeler
private void btnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
    pd.PrintPage += PrintPage;
    //here to select the printer attached to user PC
    PrintDialog printDialog1 = new PrintDialog();
    printDialog1.Document = pd;
    DialogResult result = printDialog1.ShowDialog();
    if (result == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        pd.Print();//this will trigger the Print Event handeler PrintPage
    }
}

//The Print Event handeler
private void PrintPage(object o, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (File.Exists(this.ImagePath))
        {
            //Load the image from the file
            System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(@"C:\myimage.jpg");

            //Adjust the size of the image to the page to print the full image without loosing any part of it
            Rectangle m = e.MarginBounds;

            if ((double)img.Width / (double)img.Height > (double)m.Width / (double)m.Height) // image is wider
            {
                m.Height = (int)((double)img.Height / (double)img.Width * (double)m.Width);
            }
            else
            {
                m.Width = (int)((double)img.Width / (double)img.Height * (double)m.Height);
            }
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, m);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: `e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, m);` is solved my problem.. +1

Answer (score 4):

Answer:

```
public void Print(string FileName)
{
    StringBuilder logMessage = new StringBuilder();
    logMessage.AppendLine(string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "-------------------[ START - {0} - {1} -------------------]", MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod(), DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()));
    logMessage.AppendLine(string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "Parameter: 1: [Name - {0}, Value - {1}", "None]", Convert.ToString("")));

    try
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(FileName)) return; // Prevents execution of below statements if filename is not selected.

        PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();

        //Disable the printing document pop-up dialog shown during printing.
        PrintController printController = new StandardPrintController();
        pd.PrintController = printController;

        //For testing only: Hardcoded set paper size to particular paper.
        //pd.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = new PaperSize("Custom 6x4", 720, 478);
        //pd.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = new PaperSize("Custom 6x4", 720, 478);

        pd.DefaultPageSettings.Margins = new Margins(0, 0, 0, 0);
        pd.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.Margins = new Margins(0, 0, 0, 0);

        pd.PrintPage += (sndr, args) =>
        {
            System.Drawing.Image i = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(FileName);

            //Adjust the size of the image to the page to print the full image without loosing any part of the image.
            System.Drawing.Rectangle m = args.MarginBounds;

            //Logic below maintains Aspect Ratio.
            if ((double)i.Width / (double)i.Height > (double)m.Width / (double)m.Height) // image is wider
            {
                m.Height = (int)((double)i.Height / (double)i.Width * (double)m.Width);
            }
            else
            {
                m.Width = (int)((double)i.Width / (double)i.Height * (double)m.Height);
            }
            //Calculating optimal orientation.
            pd.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = m.Width > m.Height;
            //Putting image in center of page.
            m.Y = (int)((((System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument)(sndr)).DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize.Height - m.Height) / 2);
            m.X = (int)((((System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument)(sndr)).DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize.Width - m.Width) / 2);
            args.Graphics.DrawImage(i, m);
        };
        pd.Print();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        log.ErrorFormat("Error : {0}\n By : {1}-{2}", ex.ToString(), this.GetType(), MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
    }
    finally
    {
        logMessage.AppendLine(string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "-------------------[ END  - {0} - {1} -------------------]", MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()));
        log.Info(logMessage.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Above code testing myself and working fine in my wpf kisok application.

Comment: Probably the best answer; although the log message stuff should be removed since that relies on other code not present.

Answer (score 4):

Agree with TonyM and BBoy - this is the correct answer for original 4*6 printing of label.  (args.PageBounds).  This worked for me for printing Endicia API service shipping Labels.

```
private void SubmitResponseToPrinter(ILabelRequestResponse response)
    {
        PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
        pd.PrintPage += (sender, args) =>
        {
            Image i = Image.FromFile(response.Labels[0].FullPathFileName.Trim());
            args.Graphics.DrawImage(i, args.PageBounds);
        };
        pd.Print();
    }
```

Comment: `PageBounds` worked for me where `MarginBounds` was printing way too small. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

all these answers has the problem, that's always stretching the image to pagesize and cuts off some content at trying this.

Found a little bit easier way.

My own solution only stretch(is this the right word?) if the image is to large, can use multiply copies and pageorientations.

```
                PrintDialog dlg = new PrintDialog();

            if (dlg.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
                BitmapImage bmi = new BitmapImage(new Uri(strPath));

                Image img = new Image();
                img.Source = bmi;

                if (bmi.PixelWidth < dlg.PrintableAreaWidth ||
                           bmi.PixelHeight < dlg.PrintableAreaHeight)
                {
                    img.Stretch = Stretch.None;
                    img.Width = bmi.PixelWidth;
                    img.Height = bmi.PixelHeight;
                }


                if (dlg.PrintTicket.PageBorderless == PageBorderless.Borderless)
                {
                    img.Margin = new Thickness(0);
                }
                else
                {
                    img.Margin = new Thickness(48);
                }
                img.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
                img.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;

                for (int i = 0; i < dlg.PrintTicket.CopyCount; i++)
                {
                    dlg.PrintVisual(img, "Print a Image");
                }
            }
```

Comment: Can you include the code in your answer rather than linking to it?