# How to print on network printer in C#

Tags: c#, .net, printing, network-printers

I need to print RAW data to network label printer. I have used printing using local/network printer with installed driver before. Now I am writing server application, and one of its task will be to print on many (windows) network label printers. I know I can install printer as network printer locally on the server and use the same way of printing as before.

Is there any native protocol or some "low level way" of printing to network printer without the need of installation 50+ printers on the server? I need to send RAW data, because it is label printer and print page is generated in DPL.

If there would be possibility to monitor printer state (paper, tape), it would be very nice.

Comment: Try http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322091 and then http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/939515-send-raw-data-printer-using-c

Comment: This is the way of my printing to this this time. It needs the printer installed and print to windows printer name. But thank you anyway.

Comment: I think this would help you : https://stackoverflow.com/a/18722872/5777453

Comment: Yes, I use it right now. Thanks.