# Using File.Copy to send PDF to Printer by Printer Name

Tags: c#, pdf, printing

I am trying to send an PDF file to a printer using the `File.Copy` method in C#.  When I reference the printer by name however, it always responds with

> 'Could not find a part of the path'

The printer name is fully qualified.  The user is selecting from a combo box that displays all the systems printers using the `PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters` values.

Am I missing something simple?

Example:

```
File.Copy(FileInfo.FullName, "\\\\ServerName\\PrinterName", true);
```

The `"\\\\ServerName\\PrinterName"` is directly one of the names from `PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters` collection.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18704839/send-text-file-directly-to-network-printer

Comment: When I reference it by name it says: "The network name cannot be found. Yet it populates the combo box printer list without issue. *IF* I use "\\ServerName\prt0001" it works.  But I need to reference it by the name the OS provides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use one of the printer names that comes out of the printer classes.

```
foreach (String printer in System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters)
{
     textBox1.Text += printer.ToString() + System.Environment.NewLine;
 }
```

See all the printers that are listed in this text box, copy and paste the printer name in the file.copy method.

```
File.Copy(FileInfo.FullName, **Printer name here**, true);
```