# How to print panel with picturebox and labels in it?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a `Panel` that has exactly 4 picture boxes, and labels inside. I want to print **all** the contents inside the `Panel` but it is only showing the two picture boxes - in the preview.

I have this:

[image]

But it is only showing this (*when* I click the **print** button):

[image]

Here is my code for printing:

```
private void BtnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Print(this.pnlID);
    }

    public void Print(Panel pnl)
    {
        PrinterSettings ps = new PrinterSettings();
        pnlID = pnl;
        GetPrintArea(pnl);
        prntprvw.Document = printdoc;
        printdoc.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(printdoc_printpage);
        prntprvw.ShowDialog();

    }

    public void printdoc_printpage(Object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        Rectangle pagearea = e.PageBounds;
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(MemoryImage, (pagearea.Width / 2) - (this.pnlID.Width / 2), this.pnlID.Location.Y);
    }


    Bitmap MemoryImage;
    public void GetPrintArea(Panel pnl)
    {
        MemoryImage = new Bitmap(pnl.Width, pnl.Height);
        //Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, pnl.Width, pnl.Height);
        pnl.DrawToBitmap(MemoryImage, new Rectangle(0, 0, pnl.Width, pnl.Height));
    }
```

**How can I print all the contents inside the panel?**

Comment: It isn't obvious whether the textboxes are also inside the panel.  Or it just doesn't fit the paper, [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9982579/17034).

Comment: Try this one: [How to use PrintDocument with a scrollable Panel?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57257205/7444103) (it also handles RichTextBoxes). Of course, as Hans noted, the other Controls must be child of the Panel. Otherwise, print the Form's content.

Comment: @HansPassant the textboxes isn't inside the panel, only the ID picture, the qr code, and the label inside of it.

Comment: Have you tried the method I linked? It draws the container's content from back to top, so it's probably what you need here.

Comment: @Jimi I am still learning how the code works, it makes me confused since I am new to programming

Comment: It's a self-contained method, you just need to call it specifying the ContainerControl to draw to a Bitmap. As in the notes: `var bitmap = ScrollableControlToBitmap(this.panel1, true);`, where `this.panel1` is the Panel you want to print. Pass the actual instance of your Panel to the method (`this.pnlID`), then print the returned Bitmap as you're doing now.

Comment: @Jimi thank you, it still quite confusing me though

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210841/discussion-between-kmandrew-and-jimi).